# Heroku Dataclip, How to export date column into XLS

Tags: excel, date, heroku

When a column contains a Date field, the dataclip displays it. When the "Export/Share" link is clicked and XLS selected, the resulting Date column is treated like a TEXT column in XLS.

Changing the Format in XLS does not seem to have an effect on it.

Is there a proper format for export that will make it into a Date cell?

I have tried 'MM-DD-YYY', 'MM/DD/YYY' and left it as default display (which puts the date and time in the column).

None of these are "dates" in XLS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have done some tests and I think dates are exported as YYYY-MM-DD.

I really don't have Excel installed on this computer right now, but I downloaded an xls file from dataclips and imported it on Googlesheets. Dates were correct without any conversion needed.